# JSF/RichFaces 4 issue: initiating component while rendering is false

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces, rendering

I'm having a component hiding behind a `rendered="false"`. The component still gets initialized and starting some resource wasting processes. 
How to make sure components don't get initialized when their region/component/panel has `rendered="false"`?

Source code:

**XHTML**:

```
<a4j:region rendered="false">
  <h:panelGroup rendered="false"> 
    <rich:dropDownMenu binding="#{textBlockBean.textBlockMenu}" rendered="false" />
  </h:panelGroup>
</a4j:region>
```

**JAVA**:

```
public UIComponent getTextBlockMenu() {
  if (textblockMenu == null) {
    textblockMenu = createTextBlok();
  }
  textblockMenuComponent = textblockMenu.build();
  return textblockMenuComponent;
}
```

How can I prevent

```
<rich:dropDownMenu binding="#{textBlockBean.textBlockMenu}"/>
```

from getting triggered before needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem**

By the time the EL processor gets to that tag, it's already too late to decide to *not* build the `UIComponent` instance that the tag is bound to i.e. once the EL processor gets to the `<rich:dropDownMenu/>`, it's going to call `getTextBlockMenu()`. The `rendered` attribute is a view-render time flag that simply decides whether or not to *show* the component.

**To Solve**

The decision whether to *build* the component must be made during *view-build* using the `<c:if/>` JSTL tag:

```
<a4j:region rendered="false">
  <h:panelGroup rendered="false"> 
     <c:if test="#{textBlockBean.renderCondition}">
        <rich:dropDownMenu binding="#{textBlockBean.textBlockMenu}" rendered="false" />
     </c:if>
  </h:panelGroup>
</a4j:region>
```

Where `renderCondition` is a backing bean flag that determines the availability of the component

Answer (score 0):

as the rendered-attribute is probably not static, but an EL-expr,
you could use that EL also in your getter-method, to prevent invoking the init.

Furthermore the getter is called several times during the call:

[Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

so it might be better, to rearrange your coding logic, to move init-code out of a getter method.

Comment: Although not the answer on my question, still some nice information